# Failed to try to use 2 ids on nestes routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes

I'm trying to pass 2 ids to the controller within the update action, but it does not stop, I do not recognize the first id, `student_id`. This is the definition of the route within `routes.rb`

```
post 'registers/students/:student_id/notes/:note_id/edit', to: 'registers/students/notes#update', as: :update_registers_student_note
```

While this is the part of the form_for, using the corresponding helper

```
<%= form_for @note, url: update_registers_student_note_path(:student_id,:note_id), method: :post do |f| %>
```

My question is how can I correctly pass the 2 ids of the corresponding resources, since the form only recognizes me `note_id`, and not `student_id`

Thank you

Comment: @sawa My question is how can I correctly pass the 2 ids of the corresponding resources, since the form only recognizes me `note_id`, and not `student_id`

Comment: Do you have something like this `@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])` in the action that renders the view? If so just do `update_registers_student_note_path(@student, @note)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper should works. You also can use `update_registers_student_note_path(student_id: 1, note_id: 12)`.

But I suggest you to use [nested resources](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in your routes instead.
You can write somethings like that:

```
namespace :registers do
  resources :students do
    resources :notes
  end
end
```

The new url helper will be `registers_student_note_path(<note_id>, student_id: <student_id>)` with method `PATCH`.

Comment: Thanks, the error was that in the helper I had not added the corresponding variables. I remain as follows:
`update_registers_student_note_path(student_id: params[:student_id], note_id: params[:note_id])`

Answer (score 0):

yes, you did put a right thing for [url_helpers](https://railsguide.org/rails/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet/url_helpers). You can try to open [rails console](https://railsguide.org/rails/Rails::Application/console) and try it with these command

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
update_registers_student_note_path(1,2)
```

you will see `=> "/registers/students/1/notes/2/edit"`

Comment: Irrelevant to the OP's problem!